# Query records where time in mutilple ranges in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to fetch records from "tData" where FooTime column values within a temporary time ranges table "tTime"

tData table:

```
FooTime            Value
2010-01-01 00:15   3
2010-01-01 00:30   2
2010-01-01 00:45   4
2010-01-01 01:00   5
2010-01-01 01:15   1
2010-01-01 01:30   3
2010-01-01 01:45   4
2010-01-01 02:00   12
2010-01-01 02:15   13
2010-01-01 02:30   12
2010-01-01 02:45   14
2010-01-01 03:00   15
2010-01-01 03:15   3
2010-01-01 03:30   2
2010-01-01 03:45   3
2010-01-01 04:00   5
..........
..........
..........
2010-01-02 00:15   3
2010-01-02 00:30   2
2010-01-02 00:45   4
2010-01-02 01:00   5
2010-01-02 01:15   1
2010-01-02 01:30   3
2010-01-02 01:45   4
2010-01-02 02:00   12
2010-01-02 02:15   13
2010-01-02 02:30   12
2010-01-02 02:45   14
2010-01-02 03:00   15
2010-01-02 03:15   3
2010-01-02 03:30   2
2010-01-02 03:45   3
2010-01-02 04:00   5
..........
..........
..........
```

tTime table:

```
StartTime            EndTime
2010-01-01 02:00     2010-01-01 06:00
2010-01-02 02:00     2010-01-02 06:00
....
....
....
```

According to the above sample data, the following records should be returned because the time:

```
FooTime            Value
2010-01-01 02:00   12
2010-01-01 02:15   13
2010-01-01 02:30   12
2010-01-01 02:45   14
2010-01-01 03:00   15
2010-01-01 03:15   3
2010-01-01 03:30   2
2010-01-01 03:45   3
2010-01-01 04:00   5
...
...
2010-01-01 06:00   3


2010-01-02 02:00   12
2010-01-02 02:15   13
2010-01-02 02:30   12
2010-01-02 02:45   14
2010-01-02 03:00   15
2010-01-02 03:15   3
2010-01-02 03:30   2
2010-01-02 03:45   3
2010-01-02 04:00   5
...
...
2010-01-02 06:00   3
```

Please consider that the time ranges could be different for different day, for example:
tTime table:

```
StartTime            EndTime
2010-01-01 02:00     2010-01-01 06:00
2010-01-02 19:00     2010-01-02 24:00
....
....
....
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to restrict all of the rows in tData based on *all* of the ranges defined in tTime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not near my computer with MS SQL on it but this should do the trick:

```
SELECT tData.*
FROM 
    tData
    LEFT JOIN tTime
        ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), tTime.StartTime, 101) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), tData.FooTime, 101)
WHERE
    tData.FooTime BETWEEN tTime.StartTime AND tTime.EndTime
```

Essentially join the two tables based on the Date (without time) portion of the StartTime and FooDate, then just use a BETWEEN in the WHERE clause.

As I said, I can't test this on this laptop but I'd say it'd work.

**Edit:** This assumes that there is only 1 day per row in the tTime table as per your example

**EDIT:** Just remembered that you should  be able to use BETWEEN in a JOIN criteria, so this should be better:

```
SELECT tData.*
FROM 
    tData
    INNER JOIN tTime
        ON tData.FooTime BETWEEN tTime.StartTime AND tTime.EndTime
```

Comment: there must be less than 1 day per row in tTime table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FooTime, Value
FROM tData INNER JOIN tTime 
  ON (tData.FooTime >= tTime.StartTime AND tData.EndTime <= tTime.StopTime)
```

I don't remember if a Between is allowed in a join clause, but if it is:

```
SELECT FooTime, Value
FROM tData INNER JOIN tTime 
  ON (tData.FooTime BETWEEN tTime.StartTime AND tData.EndTime)
```

Comment: Hi, your first query is not correct considering the time comparision, but your second one is correct.

Comment: sorry I did not mark your reply as answer, because both of you gave the correct answer finally, it's hard to decide. So according to the "first come first mark" rule, I gave it to mwan100. Thank you very much anyway.